# system is in superuser mode how it change to normal mode

Tags: 16.04

how to get superuser mode to normal mode. When i install my system with ubuntu 16.04.3 it is in superuser mode ican't install new softwares how it overcome
i try to install from software center and terminal
when i open my software center like this,

[image: enter image description here[1]]

i try to install from terminal

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Please explain with many details how you try to install new software. (Edit your original question to add the details.)

Answer (score 0):

You get the output

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock ...
```

when you start a second tool, that wants to do the same or similar things with the installed programs. Both the Software Center and `apt-get` 'want to do' the same or similar things. The lock is there to keep them from destroying things for each other.

When you close the Software Center, the lock should be removed, and you can run your `apt-get` command line

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```